# Alfresco default filter documentary library

Tags: javascript, filter, alfresco, document

I have some kind of document in my documentary library which have a custom metadata value. I want to  hide  these documents from document library and search result.

I know filter javascript management is in this file :

```
alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d.jar\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\slingshot\documentlibrary-v2\filters.lib.js
```

I don't know how to modify code for hiding document which has "1" as value of my metadata (sc:customMetat).

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

With below you can hide document in listing.

```
document.addAspect("sys:hidden");
```

If this doesn't works ,you need to manipulate permission.Remove access for specified users , or groups.

Comment: Thank you  Krutik Jayswal. But if i do this can i find my document with CMIS  query ?    

I'm  developping a third application wich is using this documents. I'm affraid if  i  add  sys:hidden  i can not anywhere this document.